# Why do Google SkipTo Links work with hrefs?

Tags: accessibility

How does Google get away with SkipTo links without hrefs? Whenever I try, they don't work but they work fine for Google. What kind of sorcery is this?!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was just missing tabIndex and keyDowns.